# Which MySQL type do I need to store both regular Strings and hash values?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, annotations, arrays

I'm logging changes on my JPA Entities with an extra Entity/Table `Event`:

```
@Entity
public class Event {

  private String fieldName;

  @Lob
  @Column
  private String previousValue;

  @Lob
  @Column
  private String newValue;

  // ...
}
```

Now, the fields I'm watching can have various types. If they're not Strings already but, say, `@ManyToMany` Collections, I'm building useful String representations before saving – which is all fine.

The only problem is my `User` Entity, which has a field `byte[] passwordHash`. In the MySQL table this is stored as a `tinyblob` and works fine, too. What **doesn't** work is persisting an `Event` with `newValue = new String(passwordHash, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. It obviously becomes all gibberish and I get the following error:

```
Hibernate: insert into DbEvent (timestamp, fieldName, modelId, modelName, newValue, previousValue) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
15:38:25,466 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [1] as [TIMESTAMP] - [Tue Jul 28 15:38:25 CEST 2015]
15:38:25,466 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [passwordHash]
15:38:25,466 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - [17]
15:38:25,467 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [User]
15:38:25,467 TRACE BasicBinder:81 - binding parameter [5] as [CLOB] - [G�S�G��M��j�I��
F/�-]
15:38:25,467 TRACE BasicBinder:69 - binding parameter [6] as [CLOB] - [null]
15:38:25,468  WARN SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: 22001
15:38:25,468 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - Data truncation: Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD\x17S\xEF...' for column 'newValue' at row 1
```

So **my question** would be:

Which annotations or types do I need for this to work? You see I already tried the `@Lob` (MySQL type `longtext`), because I first thought the value was too long, but it didn't help. My guess it that it has something to do with the character encoding. How do I get MySQL to not care about that? Can/Should I simply change the `String` fields of `Event` to `byte[]`?

Is there even any way to achieve this?

If my case is unclear or you need any more information in order to solve this, please let me know. I hope someone can help me :)

Thanks in advance!

---

**[Update]**

Ok, so changing `Event` to store `private byte[] previousValue` and `private byte[] newValue` seems to be sufficient. Any arguments against that?

Also, the MySQL output looks a bit screwed now:

```
+----+---------------------+--------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | timestamp           | fieldName    | previousValue | newValue                                     |
+----+---------------------+--------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
| 16 | 2015-07-28 16:19:34 | passwordHash | NULL          | 6��?�%4�
��                      |                                          aJ��e�[�½
+----+---------------------+--------------+---------------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Probably no cure for that?

Comment: If you like to store an _arbitrary_ `byte[]` as `String`, you should never use `UTF-8`, as this rejects many byte combinations - instead you should use `ISO-8859-1` which will let you convert any byte array to a `String` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Save them as String. I recommend using a Base 64 encoding method, for example:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
...
public static byte[] base64ToByte(String data) {
    Base64 decoder = new Base64();
    return decoder.decode(data);
}

public static String byteToBase64(byte[] data) {
    Base64 endecoder = new Base64();
    return endecoder.encodeToString(data);
}
...
```

I always use these methods when I need to save hashes, when you save your hashes, encode them to Base64 and when you need to compare the hashes, then decode to array of bytes, because the best practices dictate that you must compare hashes in bytes-level.

The Base64 Class is part of the commons-codec-[version].jar, I have the 1.10 version, but I share you the link where you can find it, maybe there is a newer version.

> http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec

I hope this information helps you.

Good luck.